# (MySQL) How to change the results of a view according to the user that's viewing it?

Tags: mysql, view

I have a table, named `servers`, with a single column `id`.

This table is accessed by various machines each with a different username for the database.

I want to make it so each server does not see all the information on this table, but only a subset I designate to it in order to partition the workload among the app servers.

My original idea is to rename the table (say, to "servers_table"), add another "user" column to it, and create a view (with the original name) that shows the results based on the username currently connected to the server.

My table currently looks like this:

```
id  user
 1  server1
 2  server1
 3  server2
 4  server1
 5  server2
```

My attempt was (as "server1"):

```
CREATE VIEW server AS 
SELECT id 
FROM server_orig 
WHERE usuario=SUBSTRING_INDEX(CURRENT_USER(),'@',1);
```

This, however, does not work, since `CURRENT USER()` is evaluated at `CREATE VIEW` time, not at `SELECT` time.

Therefore, running:

```
mysql -userver1 database -e "select * from server;"
```

yields:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 | 
|  2 | 
|  4 |
+----+
```

BUT so does running it as server2..

I cannot (since the program is closed source) change the original `select` statement (and that would also incur eventually changing the `insert/update` statements too).

Is there a way this can be accomplished purely on the MySQL side?

Comment: also, I know this sounds incredibly insane for such a simple question, but IF it solves this problem, the database can also be migrated to Postgre. It's small enough, and this gain would certainly justify the hurdles around this. Performance's not critical at this point, this database has most configuration data, and will only get a thousand or so queries an hour..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hint from the current_user() [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user):

> For stored procedures and functions and views defined with the SQL SECURITY INVOKER characteristic, CURRENT_USER() returns the object's invoker.

On the other hand, in PostgreSQL you can do the same (with the `current_user` function, which behaves exactly as desired), and with good design and config the performance wouldn't be any worse - however, I don't think that this feature would make migrating to PostgreSQL any sense (especially given that your app code is closed...)

Comment: I've tried it with SQL SECURITY INVOKER and it works perfectly! Thank you for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

Please run this SQL Query:

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

- [`USER()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) reports how you attempted to authenticate in MySQL
- [`CURRENT_USER()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) reports how you were allowed to authenticate in MySQL

In reality, `USER()` is probably better because it reveals the DB Connection's point of original. You should probably create a Stored Procedure or Stored Function (that returns a Comma-Separated List of ids with `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM server_orig WHERE usuario=SUBSTRING_INDEX(CURRENT_USER(),'@',1);`)

That way, you can make a Stored Procedure or Stored Function with SQL SECURITY DEFINER and still know who originated the Query. CURRENT_USER() would be the definer. You will need to use the `USER()` function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `USER()` instead of `CURRENT_USER()`. 
Also leave `SQL SECURITY DEFINER`. Using `INVOKER` you won't be able to select view without granting permissions for every table it uses.